# iphone update uilabel and uiimageview

Tags: iphone, multithreading, uiimageview, uilabel

I have three labels and one uimageview object. The labels displays info about the image. My problem is that I can't update both the labels and image. The code below updates only labels. How to update uiimageview (ARView2) as well?

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput 
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer 
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection 
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    bufferContent = createIplImageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer);   
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateLabels) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

    [pool drain];
} 
-(void)updateLabels
{
    results = tracking(bufferContent);
    labelFPS.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f ms",results.resultTime];
    labelKeypoints.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %d",results.noKeypoints];
    labelRecognised.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",results.resultTime];
    [ARview2 setImage:[self UIImageFromIplImage:results.resultImg]];

}
```

When I use this code:

```
    - (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput 
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer 
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection 
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    bufferContent = createIplImageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer); 
    results = tracking(bufferContent);
    labelFPS.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f ms",results.resultTime];
    labelKeypoints.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %d",results.noKeypoints];
    labelRecognised.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",results.resultTime];
    [ARView2 performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:[self UIImageFromIplImage:results.resultImg] waitUntilDone:YES];

    [pool drain];
}
```

only ARView2 is updated with new image. But labels don't change their values.

FINAL ANSWEAR
ok. Somehow I manage to achieve my goal. I don't know if it's correct but it works. I post the code, hope somebody will find it useful.

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput 
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer 
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection 
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    bufferContent = createIplImageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer); 
    results = tracking(bufferContent);

    [arView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:[self UIImageFromIplImage:results.resultImg] waitUntilDone:YES];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(updateLabels) withObject:nil];

    [pool drain];
} 
-(void)updateLabels
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    labelFPS.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f ms",results.resultTime];
    labelKeypoints.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %d",results.noKeypoints];
    labelRecognised.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",results.resultTime];
    [pool drain];
    pool = nil;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `ARview2` ?

Comment: it is UIImageView object and this is how I declare it UIImageView *ARview2;

Comment: What do you mean when you say you can't update both?

Comment: UIIViewImage is not updated. Only labels are.

Comment: Please insert code where you initialize labels and ARview2. PS don't use first capital letter for the names of your variables, it's bad practice. This naming macro is reserved for object types.

Comment: I don't initialize them directly. I added them with Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

- Check if you connected properly ARview2 in UI;
- What is in results.resultImg? Is it a valid image?

Comment: yes it is connected and yes it is valid image. I published code which updates UIImageView but does not update labels. I don't know what to do to update labels and UIImageView in the same time